# encounted error '6985' '6A88' during installing the .cap file when debugging in JCIDE

Tags: java, debugging, applet, ide, javacard

I am using JCIDE to debug its sample applet- walletdemo.

I encounted **error 6985**

> conditions not satisfied'and 6A88'Referenced data or reference data
>   not found

during installation of the **.cap** file on the **JCVM** when debugging. But I don't know what's wrong and what to do.

The following is part of the applet:

```
private WalletDemoApplet(byte bArray[], short bOffset, byte bLength)
{
   /* cardid=new byte[MAX_NUM_CARDID];
    key  =new byte[MAX_NUM_KEYS];
    for (byte i = 0; i < MAX_NUM_KEYS; i++)
        key[i] =i;
    for (byte i = 0; i < MAX_NUM_CARDID; i++)
        cardid[i] =i;*/

    balance  = 0;
    integral = 0;


    Key = (DESKey)KeyBuilder.buildKey(KeyBuilder.TYPE_DES, KeyBuilder.LENGTH_DES3_2KEY, false);         
    //cipherDES_ECB_NOPAD = Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.ALG_DES_ECB_NOPAD, false);
    cipherDES_ECB_NOPAD = Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.ALG_DES_CBC_ISO9797_M1, false);
    myRandomS = RandomData.getInstance(RandomData.ALG_SECURE_RANDOM);

    pin = new OwnerPIN(PIN_TRY_LIMIT,   MAX_PIN_SIZE);
    cardID = new byte[10];
    output = new byte[16];
    //input = new byte[16];
    bRand = false;
    ExternalMark=false;
    verifyMark=false;
    byte iLen = bArray[bOffset]; // aid length
    bOffset = (short) (bOffset+iLen+1);
    byte cLen = bArray[bOffset]; // info length
    bOffset = (short) (bOffset+cLen+1);
    byte aLen = bArray[bOffset]; // applet data length
    bOffset = (short)(bOffset+1);        
    byte pinLen = bArray[bOffset];


    // The installation parameters contain the PIN
    // initialization value
    pin.update(bArray, (short)(bOffset+1), pinLen);

    // Initialize key
    bOffset = (short)(bOffset+pinLen+1);
    byte keyLen = bArray[bOffset];
    Key.setKey(bArray, (short)(bOffset+1));

    // Initialize cardID
    bOffset = (short)(bOffset+keyLen+1);
    byte idLen = bArray[bOffset];
    Util.arrayCopy(bArray, (short)(bOffset+1), cardID, (short)0, (short)idLen); 

    register(); 
}
public static void install(byte[] bArray, short bOffset, byte bLength) {
    // GP-compliant JavaCard applet registration
    new WalletDemoApplet(bArray, bOffset, bLength);

}
```

Comment: Can you put the code of your applet here? Does it used any special cryptography function in the program?   Sometimes the programmer used some classes in the applet that your card may doesn't support them. In this situations you'll receive such as this error.

Comment: Thank you for your consideration.Beause the entire source code is very long,I  have put part of the code which may result in the error .Can you find some clues for me?

Comment: What kind of card do you use? Which algorithms does it support? Unfortunately I can't help based on this little part of your program. If you have not any concern about your program disclosure and its copy right share the it with us to help.

Comment: btw please change the line `cipherDES_ECB_NOPAD = Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.ALG_DES_CBC_ISO9797_M1, false);` to this : `cipherDES_ECB_NOPAD = Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.ALG_DES_ECB_NOPAD, false);` and try again to upload the _.cap_ file. (As you can see in your program you instantiate a cipher with `DES_CBC_ISO9797_M1` algorithm to your cipher object named `cipherDES_ECB_NOPAD`. moreover it is possible that the card not supporting `ALG_DES_CBC_ISO9797_M1` algorithm)

Comment: Hi ,TheGoodUser! Sorry to reply you so late. Beause JCIDE comes with the simulator, I use the simulator of JCIDE itself. I have changed the code as you suggested ,but it still failed with code 6985 conditions not satisfied.

Comment: Oops! As far as I know, SW=0x6985 means that your card is locked or the keys that you use for authentication are not correct.

Comment: Many thanks for your help.  I just added a breakpoint,and i find   the line 'pin.update(bArray, (short)(bOffset+1), pinLen);'  resulted in the error code.But I don't know why.

Comment: `bArray[bOffset];` in this method is the length of your applet's AID. why did you use it as the length of the pin in line  `byte pinLen = bArray[bOffset];` ? (Note that you called `pin.update(bArray, (short)(bOffset+1), pinLen);` in applet's constructor, and this method call only once and only in the installation process and not anymore)

Comment: Please set `MAX_PIN_SIZE=(byte)0x05` and then replace the line `pin.update(bArray, (short)(bOffset+1), pinLen);` with `pin.update(bArray,(short)bOffset+1,(byte)5);` and try again and inform me about the result. (Using this new program, you set the first 5 byte of you Applet AID as the pin of your applet). BTW I must mention that 0X6985 means that your card is locked or your keys are not correct. Can you install another applet now? Or even listing installed applet?

Comment: Hi,TheGoodUser! I changed the code as you said. But it can't load  successfully either. Other applets  however load successfully.

Comment: Hi,my friend! I am very excited to tell you it load successfully now. It just lost the default installation parameter . I  set the application specific parameters ,and it  runs without any error now. Thank you for your help and consideration,my friend.

Comment: Hey.Do you mean the above program without any change works fine now? Can you please explain more how did you solve the issue? What is the default installation parameters and where did you set them? in the program or in the installer tool parameters?

Comment: Yes,the program works fine now without any change.  I just open 'debug configurations' dialog box in JCIDE and set the application specific parameters'081122334455667788' in applet install properties.Then  It works without any error.

Comment: What does these numbers mean? Why did you choose them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the problem is not caused by the algorithm, maybe it's because a installation parameter is required when install.You can try to set the installation parameter, such as  “08112233445566778810404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F080010203040506070”.

I hope that i can help you.

Comment: Thank your answer.It load successfully now.

Comment: @andy007 If this solution solved your issue, you must check it as answer (by clicking on the V mark in the left side of the answer.)

Comment: And what is this default installation parameters? How we can set them? In the program body or in the installer tool? What does that mean? (The first quarter and the third quarter : i.e. `08112233445566778810` and `080010203040506070`)?

Comment: @TheGoodUser  In fact there need to specify a parameters during this Applet installation. Usually, can be found in the configuration parameter of the Applet.
In JCIDE or JCOP software, for example, called 'Application Specific Parameters' in the 'Applet Install Properties' window.

Comment: What does these numbers mean? Why did you choose them? i.e why you didn't use 03491249871897389175981 for example?! isn't there any way to calculate the correct value?

Answer (score 1):

@TheGoodUser

The first quarter and the third quarter : i.e. 08112233445566778810and 080010203040506070.  I based on this code,

```
// The installation parameters contain the PIN
// initialization value
pin.update(bArray, (short)(bOffset+1), pinLen);

// Initialize key
bOffset = (short)(bOffset+pinLen+1);
byte keyLen = bArray[bOffset];
Key.setKey(bArray, (short)(bOffset+1));

// Initialize cardID
bOffset = (short)(bOffset+keyLen+1);
byte idLen = bArray[bOffset];
Util.arrayCopy(bArray, (short)(bOffset+1), cardID, (short)0, (short)idLen);
```

there need to three parameters: PIN, key and cardID.

As long as the Tag-Len-Value Formats, these numbers can be other Numbers.

Specific you can see "GlobalPlatform specification".

Comment: Thank you. And now, what is  PIN, what is key and what is cardID?